# Search github file contents by filename

Tags: github

I am trying to identify use cases of a specific python package on github.

Is there a way you could search all `requirements.txt` files on repositories written in python for a string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 2022 and GitHub search has changed a bit.

You can now just use the more flexible `path:` operator like this:

```
path:/^requirements.txt$/  django
```

[Search results here](https://github.com/search?q=path%3A%2F%5Erequirements.txt%24%2F%20%20django&type=code). By default a search term now searches both the filename and the content, so to limit it to just filename/path we use `path:`. Also we use a regex to specify we want files named exactly `requirements.txt` and not things like `dev-requirements.txt` which `path:requirements.txt` would match.

I couldn't find a way to just search for requirements files in Python repos though. You can specify a language with `language:python` but that applies at a per-file level, not at the repo level and those files aren't Python themselves. Fortunately `requirements.txt` files seem to almost entirely be used in Python projects.

More info on GitHub's powerful new search [can be found here](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax).

Answer (score 5):

#### From the Web UI

In https://github.com/search, type :

```
django filename:requirements.txt language:python in:requirements.txt
```

[like this](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=django%20filename%3Arequirements.txt%20language%3Apython%20in%3Arequirements.txt&ref=simplesearch) :
[image]

#### From Github API

```
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=django+in:requirements.txt+filename:requirements.txt+language:python+org:openmicroscopy
```

For the Github API case, you have to give a user, an organization or a repository

Check [Search Code doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code)

Note that filename filter & string data are no exact match